# Extract numerics from text field

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, text, numeric

Got a table that contains a field similar to the following

`856655.460000000000000+0.000000000000000+2200121.020000000000000
    164171.720000000000000+0.000000000000000+421637.020000000000000
    0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000
    103176.220000000000000+0.000000000000000+264984.210000000000000`

What I need to do is extract the numeric fields and total them. There may be a different number of numeric fields within the column, but they'll all be separated by the '+' symbol
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a limit to how many numbers will be in a column? Will the numbers always have 15 decimals places? Is there a limit to the number of digit to the left of the decimal? I think I have a solution or at least something that might help you along.

Comment: There is no limit to the number in a column, it will always contain 15 decimals, there is no limit on the numbers to the left

Answer (score 1):

Try this. to get a better answer you should add more detail about how the table is structured.

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(MAX) = '856655.460000000000000+0.000000000000000+2200121.020000000000000+164171.720000000000000+0.000000000000000+421637.020000000000000+0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000+0.000000000000000+103176.220000000000000+0.000000000000000+264984.210000000000000';
DECLARE @newVal VARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #Table
(
           value DECIMAL(30, 15)
);

WHILE LEN(@val) > 0
    BEGIN
       IF(@val LIKE '%+%')
          BEGIN
             SET @newVal = LEFT(@val, CHARINDEX('+', @val));
             INSERT INTO #table 
                VALUES
                (
                    CONVERT( DECIMAL(30, 15), LEFT(@newVal, LEN(@newVal) - 1))
                );
             SET @val = SUBSTRING(@val, LEN(@newVal)+1, LEN(@Val)-LEN(@newVal));
          END;
       ELSE
          BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Table
                VALUES 
                (
                    CONVERT( DECIMAL(30, 15), REPLACE(@val, '+', ''))
                );
             SET @val = '';
          END;
    END;

SELECT * FROM #Table
SELECT sum(value) FROM #Table;
DROP TABLE #Table
```

**Edit:**

To retrofit this to work on a table you could add a `cursor` which loops through each row in your table, runs the above query and updates the table with the results from the sum. I'm sure there are better ways but if this is a one time cleanup, it should work. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you will have to modify this to fit your situation, but the basic concept is to transform your plus sign separated string into xml and then use the [nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method to break it apart.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;

declare @string varchar(250)
declare @xml xml

set @string = '856655.460000000000000+0.000000000000000+2200121.020000000000000'

set @xml = ('<r>' + REPLACE(@string,'+','</r><r>') + '</r>')

select  t.v.value('r[1]', 'decimal(25,15)') as Value1, 
        t.v.value('r[2]', 'decimal(25,15)') as Value2,
        t.v.value('r[3]', 'decimal(25,15)') as Value3,
        t.v.value('r[4]', 'decimal(25,15)') as Value4
into #temp
from @xml.nodes('/') AS t(v)

select * 
from #temp

select coalesce(Value1, 0) + coalesce(Value2, 0) + 
coalesce(Value3, 0) + coalesce(Value4, 0) as 'Total'
from #temp
```

You will have to add more code to the query that selects into #temp for each potential value in your string. If you have a massive amount of possible numbers this may not scale.

Hope this helps you get to what you need.

Comment: this answer only works if there is 4 values or less within the record. OP states there could be any number of values